# Rails: How to render repetitive form block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, rendering, haml

In order to not repeat myself, I would like to create a function that render a form block (text field or text area) in a specific way. I want a result like this one (using Haml, and twitter-bootstrap):

```
.form-block.input-prepend
    %span.add-on>
        %i.icon.icon-home
    = f.text_field :name, :value => @store.name, :placeholder => 'Company Name'
```

To do that, I created a file `views/layouts/_form-block.html.haml` where I inserted the following code:

```
.form-block.input-prepend
    %span.add-on>
        %i{ :class => "icon icon-#{icon}" }
    = yield
```

And I call the block in my view using:

```
- render :template => 'layouts/_form-block', :locals => { :icon => 'home' } do
    = f.text_field :name, :value => @store.name, :placeholder => 'Company Name'
```

But It doesn't work. I have the following error `'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.`

Do you have any idea? Is this the best way to do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `= yield` to pass a block, you need to render as a layout. Use `render :layout =>` instead of `render :template =>`.

Comment: Thanks mckeed, but unfortunately, I get the following error: `Missing partial layouts/_form-block with {:handlers=>[:haml, :coffee, :erb, :builder], :locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html]}. Searched in:
  * "/Users/Hassinus/www/rails/color01/app/views"`

Comment: Weird. That's where the file is, right? app/views/layouts/_form-block.html.haml ?

Comment: This is the right answer. You just should call layout without `_`: `= render :layout => 'layouts/form_block do`. And the file name should be: `_form_block.html.haml`