# Haml nesting with rendered partial in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, haml, partial-views

Consider a partial.haml like this:

```
- haml_tag :body, {:id => @instance_var}
```

What I'm trying to do is to **nest haml content under a rendered partial**. Something like:

```
= render 'partial_file' do
    %h1 My test
    %p Trying to nest under a partial output.
```

But this is causing view errors like:

```
'nil' is not an ActiveModel-compatible object that returns a valid partial path.
```

Is there any similar solution to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I solved this per the recommendation in [Rails: How to render repetitive form block?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12011849/51835) by specifying the render as `:layout`:

```
= render :layout => 'partial_file' do
    %h1 My test
```